# Cannot put the text in input box in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to make the input box show some text in the asp.net using c#, but after I run the code behind, nothing is displayed in the input box. The ui is RadNumericTextBox uiDistance. In class, I put this.uiDistance.Text = "123"; But in the webpage after run the code. I cannot see "123" is put in the uiDistance text box. How can I fix it?

Here is my aspx UsageControl2SubControl1.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UsageControl2SubControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebControls.UsageControl2SubControl1" %>
<asp:HiddenField ID="uiRemoved" Value="false" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="uiID" runat="server" />
<div class="form-group">    

    <div class="col-md-2 customColumnPadding">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="uiToLocation" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true"
                    OnTextChanged="uiToLocation_Leave" EmptyMessage="<%$ Resources:ResourceHKEx,Arrive_To %>" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 customColumnPadding" id="uiColumnDistance" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="uiDistance" runat="server" Width="100%" MinValue="0" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2" EmptyMessage="<%$ Resources:Resource,Distance %>" />
    </div>

</div>
<div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
```

And Here is my code behind: UsageControl2SubControl1.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

namespace WebControls
{
    public partial class UsageControl2SubControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(uiRemoved.Value))
            {
                this.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        protected void uiAdd_Click(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.ImageButtonClickEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void uiRemove_Click(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.ImageButtonClickEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void RadComboBoxProduct_ItemsRequested(object sender, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void uiAdd_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {


        }

        protected void uiRemove_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void uiToLocation_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            this.uiDistance.Text = "123";

        }
    }// end class
}// end namespace
```

Comment: it triggering when you write something in this field. Do you know it?

Comment: Sorry, I am not so sure. Can you explain a little bit? How can I solve the issue?

Comment: have you put break point on uiToLocation_Leave event to see does that event triggers?

Comment: @want_to_be_calm yes, say me when it have to fired and i will write to you code

Comment: @KevinShah , Yes, I put the breakpoint in it and it does run.

Comment: @evilGenius In the above , you can see RadTextbox uiTolocation, when it is onTextChanged. Then the uiTolocation_Leave will be triggered and try do update the uiDistance text.

Comment: @want_to_be_calm uiToLocation_Leave triggered when you write in this telerik:RadTextBox. If you wanna add default value just move your code in page_load or add declaratively on aspx page

Comment: @evilGenius what I am doing is after the user type in uiToLocation , I will get the content of uiLocation and then do something in uiToLocation_Leave and then update the uiDistance. Even I see this.uiDistance.text = "123" is running. But the webpage of uiDistance does not show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update your aspx code little bit

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2 customColumnPadding">           
         <telerik:RadTextBox ID="uiToLocation" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true"
                    OnTextChanged="uiToLocation_Leave" EmptyMessage="<%$ Resources:ResourceHKEx,Arrive_To %>" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 customColumnPadding" id="uiColumnDistance" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="uiDistance" runat="server" Width="100%" MinValue="0" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2" EmptyMessage="<%$ Resources:Resource,Distance %>" />
    </div>

</div>
  </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

As your textbox is only inside the update panel so, on post back only that portion is partially updated, you need to put `RadNumericTextBox` inside the update panel too.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will works only when you tab out from `uiToLocation` textbox.

If you want to show it when page loads, just move your code in to `Page_Load` event instead `uiToLocation_Leave`.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(uiRemoved.Value))
            {
                this.Visible = false;
            }
            this.uiDistance.Text = "123"; // it will assign when page loads.
        }
```

If you want to load it only once when page loads, use IsPostaback, see below.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(uiRemoved.Value))
            {
                this.Visible = false;
            }

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                this.uiDistance.Text = "123"; // it will assign only once when page loads.
            }
        }
```

Comment: What I need is I want uiDistance to be updated when I type something in uiToLocation, and I find it after I type in uiToLocation, it does go to uiToLocation_Leave and run this.uiDistance.text = "123", however, I see in the webpage, nothing is changed.

Comment: If  this is what you want, follow @Kevin Shah's answer. Move your textbox inside update panel.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong property. Use `Value` not `Text`

```
protected void uiToLocation_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.uiDistance.Value = "123";
}
```

As always, check the documentation. See: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/numerictextbox/features/getting-and-setting-values

Answer (score 0):

IT seems you are using the wrong property to assign value to telerik Textbox.

Use `.Value` property as `.Text` property if for default aspx Textbox control

```
this.uiDistance.Value= "123"
```

Comment: Please avoid posting duplicate answers. [Please see my answer posted 15min before yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56016955/4665)